# Voros' one-dimensional zeta function

Tags: partition-function

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005029, formula 23, Voros evaluates and gets the following spectral theta /(semiclassical) function

$$ \sum (E_{n}+\lambda )^{-s}= \frac{\Gamma (s-1/2)}{\Gamma(s)\sqrt \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(V(x)+\lambda)^{s-1/2})}= \zeta (s, \lambda)$$

$$ H=p^{2}+V(x). $$

I believe he has used the identity for the Gamma function $$ \Gamma (s-1/2)a^{1/2-s} = \int_{0}^{\infty} dt t^{s-1/2}e^{-at} $$

However how could I compute the derivative $ \frac{ \partial }{\partial s}\zeta (s, \lambda)$ at $ s=0 $ should I ignore all the divergent terms and simply take the finite part?